# On the TV show “Blindspot,” have they ever explained the source of the knowledge behind the tattoos?

Tags: blindspot

The premise of the show *Blindspot* (2015) is that amnesiac Jane Doe has been copiously covered with tattoos by one or conspirators and delivered into the hands of an FBI team. Each week the team "solves" the puzzle of a tattoo or combination of tattoos to find a clue that will lead them to some sort of criminal enterprise: Terrorists buying weapons, terrorists sneaking bombs into New York, cybercrimes, government conspiracies or the like.

We eventually learn that the tattoos were put on Jane by

> the terrorist group Sandstorm, and Jane's adoptive mother, and that Jane volunteered to be tattooed and have her memory erased

But it's never explained where the knowledge behind some of the event-based tattoos comes from. Often a tattoo that is at least several months old is "solved" when it produces a number or phrase that ties into an event that's occurring in realtime, such as a series of scores from a college football team or a theft that's just occurred that day.

Initially I thought this strongly suggested that Jane was from the future, and that this was more of a sci-fi series, but her less exotic origins were eventually explained.

So has there ever been any explanation, in or outside of the narrative, how some of the tattoos seem to rely on foreknowledge of events?

Comment: It was a good starting premise that just got stupider and stupider as the series progressed. Sigh.

Comment: @RoboKaren Seems to be a pattern among TV shows.

Answer (score 0):

On re-watching the episode *Heave Fiery Knot* on netflix, near the end it was revealed that Sandstorm got much of the information for the tattoos from sources in various law enforcement agencies including a high-ranking member of the Department of Justice.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I don't think that resolves the questions raised where the tattoo clues trigger timely responses to things like terror attacks that weren't even planned when Jane was tattooed. Fan speculation was that the clues came from either time travel or some precognitive system.